# Automatically call method after data is added to Django DB

Tags: python, django, django-models

After adding data to a certain table in DB through `Django admin` I want  a method to be called automatically to process this data (before or after it was added to DB) and save the output in a different table, so that when user logs in the view doesn't have to wait for processing of that data and only query a table for prepared output.

Is there a handler/method that allows me to hook up to data being added to DB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [pre_save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/signals/#pre-save) and the [post_save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/signals/#post-save) signals.